# Robust ANCOVA in R with package WRS2

Tags: r

The function `ancboot` from the `WRS` package performs a one-way ANCOVA with one covariate using 20% trimmed means and bootstrapping:

```
ancboot(formula, data, tr = 0.2, nboot = 599, sm = FALSE, fr1 = 1, fr2 = 1,
        pr = TRUE, pts = NA)
```

The command returns an object of class `ancova` containing trimmed means at 5 design points:

```
[1] "Note: confidence intervals are adjusted to control FWE"
[1] "But p-values are not adjusted to control FWE"
[1] "Taking bootstrap samples. Please wait."
$output
X n1 n2 DIF TEST ci.low ci.hi p.value
[1,] 2 15 30 -1.277778 -1.846494 -3.234577 0.6790212 0.0855
[2,] 4 38 50 -1.066667 -2.139515 -2.476449 0.3431158 0.0440
[3,] 4 38 50 -1.066667 -2.139515 -2.476449 0.3431158 0.0335
[4,] 5 42 50 -1.092308 -2.256915 -2.460882 0.2762670 0.0320
[5,] 6 25 41 -1.333333 -2.341798 -2.943341 0.2766743 0.0300
$crit
[1] 2.8277
```

However, I had expected to report the robust ANCOVA much like a conventional (parametric) ANCOVA, including an omnibus *p* value, 95% CI, *F*, and [df]. How can I get the desired output with a robust ANCOVA (i.e., with trimmed means and bootstrapping)?

Comment: WRS or WRS2 package?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik I just double-checked and I’m actually using WRS version 0.27.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the [raw source file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicebread/WRS/master/pkg/R/Rallfun-v27e.R) for any trace of methods, but it would appear the result has no special class, which means no special method can be defined. Ask package author/maintainer to include this feature or contribute the source code.